# Use 2 Title Images in JQUERY UI Dialog based on php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a php condition and need two different images to potentially display.  Is there some way to create two different titles for different classes? Or maybe a different way in the jquery?  Right now I changed the CSS background img of my dialog box to a custom one.  Is it possible to somehow delete this background attribute for the title div when the pop_out div is present?   Not sure you need to see it but my php is something like below, and I need a different title for both situations, and really am just lost at the moment on how to do it.  Thanks

```
if ($out_of_stock != 'Y') { 
 <div id="pop_in">
 </div>
} else{
 <div id="pop_out">
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was actually easy just added this in the ajax call after my dialog call

```
 if ($('#pop_out').length){
    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css('background', 'none');
  }
```